# How to get 802.11 protocol type of wireless interface in Debian 8.6?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, 802.11

I have one wireless interface that connected to an access point (AP), and I want to know which type of 802.11 protocol (e.g. 802.11n or 802.11b) is used to communicate with AP. I know there is a Linux command `iw` can get some information of wireless interface, such as `signal strength`. But I don't find how to get 802.11 protocol type by `iw`.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `iw dev wlan0 station dump` includes the currently used transfer and receive bitrate to and from the AP, and this indicates which protocol (802.11b, 802.11g, 802.11g) is currently used if you know e.g. it's in the 2.4 GHz band.

The output of `iw dev wlan0 scan dump` shows which rates the AP accepts, and again this indicates which protocol(s) the AP supports.

I don't know any way to directly get the protocol by name.

Comment: The iwconfig <interface> command should also list the frequency of the link, and some google-fu should link that frequency to a given protocol as, I believe, each protocol (a, b, g, n, etc) use their own set of frequencies.

Comment: @music2myear: Sorry, that's not correct. b, g, n for example all use the same frequencies. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Protocol).

Comment: Today I learned.